# Plotting data in order of date

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

The aim is to plot a historical plot in r. using the following data

```
      date new_cases
1   22/01/2020        NA
2   23/01/2020         0
3   24/01/2020         1
4   25/01/2020         0
5   26/01/2020         3
6   27/01/2020         0
7   28/01/2020         0
8   29/01/2020         1
9   30/01/2020         0
10  31/01/2020         2

... etc.
```

I have never plotted like this, the only thing I know is using

```
plot(data$new_cases)
```

But surely there is a more a aesthetically pleasing way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Convert the date column with the as.Date function.  Then plot(x=data$date, y=data$new_cases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, you can convert the date column to `date` (as suggested above) using `as.Date`. Then, you can plot and label your graph.

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%d/%m/%Y")
plot(new_cases ~ date, df, xaxt = "n", type = "l")
axis(1, df$date, format(df$date, "%d/%m/%Y"), cex.axis = .7)
```

[image]

Another option is to use `tidyverse` and convert the date, then pipe into `ggplot2`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format =  "%d/%m/%Y")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date,new_cases)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Or if you just want points, then you can do as @Dave2e suggested:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%d/%m/%Y")

plot(x=df$date, y=df$new_cases)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For completness, `date` is a poor and potentially perilous name for variable and my result in a namespace conflict as `date` corresponds to base and `lubridate` functions. When using this data, I would suggest that you rename column to `case_date` or equivalent.

On another matter, if you are using [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org) you may want to explore [`lubridate`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org), which is part of [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org).

```
# pasted_data <- read.delim(pipe("pbpaste"))
library("tidyverse")
library("tidyr")
library("lubridate")
pasted_data %>%
  separate(
    col = 1,
    sep = "\\s+",
    into = c("col_ind", "case_date", "cases"),
    convert = TRUE
  ) %>% 
  mutate(case_date = dmy(case_date)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = case_date, y = cases)) +
  geom_line()
```

---

*For posterity, ff pasted in the available format, data should be separated into distinct columns. While in `tidyverse`, this can be achieved using `tidy::separate`.*